# Can't use lambdas as breakpoint conditions while debugging in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I use lambdas in my code, but can't use them as breakpoint conditions while debugging that code. It pops out a message:

```
Problem processing VM event:
Breakpoint: 'Line 112 in MyClass.method() (my.package)'
Error: Failed to evaluate breakpoint condition
'Iterables.toCollection(this).stream().anyMatch(n->n.isOk())'
Reason: Lambdas evaluation is not supported
Would you like to stop at the breakpoint?
```

Why is that and what can I do to use lambdas in breakpoints?

Comment: You coudl break in your `isOk()` method as this is what your lambda does. Also you could write `Foo::isOk` instead of `n -> n.isOk()`, where `Foo` is the class of `n`

Comment: @fge A fine workaround, but why are lambdas not supported?

Comment: Well, if they are method references you would go into the method anyway. I suspect that if your lambda were "code" then you could break into it.

Comment: @fge Yeah I see that, I'm asking about what makes lambdas unavailable in breakpoints? Is it that they're not yet implemented in the IDE, or is that impossible due to Java runtime restrictions, or something else?

Comment: Try creating new feature request/bugreport in JetBrains' YouTrack. Lambda evaluation works in evaluate expression window while debugging so I don't see a reason why it should not work for conditional breakpoints.

Comment: I feel like noone really got the point of the question. 5 years later i have the same problem. Lambdas in conditional breakpoints won't compile.

Comment: @Chris I feel you bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea 15 has got support for lambda debugging. Refer https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/

Comment: Not Filters though